# SQL Join duplicating values on table A

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out a solution for a problem but so far no success.

Table A:

```
COMPANY - STORE - CODE
  A        ASG     H       
  A        ASG     S
  A        BSG     S
  A        CSG     H
  A        CSG     S
```

Table B:

```
COMPANY - STORE - CODE - VALUE
  A        ASG     H      100 
  A        BSG     H      200
  A        CSG     S      100
```

I need to get the column "Value" from table B written into table A a single time, without duplicating lines. If I join them using the column "Code", I get the value written only one time, but the join fails sometimes, as you can notice on the store "BSG", it's code is S on table A, but H on table B.

How can I get the value from table B written only a single time on table A? Also, sometimes on table B, the code can end up being an S, and the store on Table A only has a code H.

Can anyone help me?

Desired Output:

```
COMPANY - STORE - CODE  - VALUE
  A        ASG     H    - 100    
  A        ASG     S    -  0
  A        BSG     S    - 200
  A        CSG     H    -  0
  A        CSG     S    - 100
```

Comment: Do you also say , table B will never have 2 rows with same store- code combination?

Comment: Table B will only have a single value, but it can be under either S or H

Comment: @Renato is there a reason that you accepted an answer that does not return your expected result? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73f5abb7acb2abe6d876dfc1c42584a7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by a.company, a.store, a.code order by a.company) = 1
             then b.value else 0 end
        end) as value
from a left join
     b
     on a.company = b.company and a.store = b.store and a.code = b.code
order by a.company, a.store, a.code, value desc;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it probably works but it ruined the performance of my query, it's taking longer than 10 minutes to run after I implemented your solution.

Comment: You must have a very large set of data.  At the very least an index on `b(company, store, code)` will help the query.

Answer (score 1):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select company, store, code, 
       case when rn = 1 then value else 0 end value
from (
  select a.*, b.value,
         row_number() over (partition by a.company, a.store order by a.code = b.code desc) rn
  from TableA a left join TableB b 
  on b.company = a.company and b.store = a.store
) t
order by company, store, code
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3463016f5c36a9a17357a07430324efd).
Results:

```
> company | store | code | value
> :------ | :---- | :--- | ----:
> A       | ASG   | H    |   100
> A       | ASG   | S    |     0
> A       | BSG   | S    |   200
> A       | CSG   | H    |     0
> A       | CSG   | S    |   100
```